# Performance of Loggly when logs are generated from 12000 client systems simultaneously

Tags: java, logback, loggly

I have 600 restaurant stores. Each store consists of 20 systems of type Point Of Sale, Kitchen Display System and Server. So, will Loggly work when logs will be generated from 12000(600 X 20) client systems simultaneously? I want to integrate Point Of Sale, Kitchen Display System and Server with Loggly so that logs generated from these systems using java Logback will be posted to Loggly dashboard. Logs can be generated from each system from multiple threads at the same time. Moreover, logs can be generated from all the systems from multiple threads simultaneously. Can Loggly support such a scenario? Will there be any performance issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to talk to the Loggly people directly.  They are the only folks who will be able to answer these questions accurately.

Bear in mind that even if you found some other Loggly customer who is logging from ~12000 systems, there experience won't necessarily generalize to your use-case.  There are other equally important "variables"; e.g. network bandwidth, latency and reliability, and the rate at which your systems generate log messages.

Answer (score 0):

Being agent-less, Loggly can be a good option, since there are two ways in which you can send logs: by using Syslog or directly via HTTP. If you use Syslog, the large number of clients will sit behind one or more syslog servers, which then will send data to Loggly. If you send via HTTP directly from each client to Loggly, you will be hitting Loggly's collectors which can handle large volumes, so you should be fine.

You may want to touch base with Loggly here: https://www.loggly.com/plans-and-pricing/